# How can I access three linux synchronously if one get failure

Tags: linux

I have three redhat systems with three different ip address (10.10.10.3 (A), 10.10.10.4 (B), 10.10.10.5 (C)). I am accessing these three machines separately now.

But I would like to access three machines with one logical address . Means if I do ssh to A and A is down in case it will go to B and if B is down it will go to C else loop end.

A->B->C->NO connection(failure)
Could anyone please suggest the changes I need to do in three machines to achieve the same.

Comment: It is redhat 6.5 . The linux machines are like clone to each other

Comment: If you don't only need this for ssh you might think about implementing a loadbalancer

Comment: Hm, and how is "is down" defined? How should machine `B` decide if machine `A` is down or not?

Comment: Yes exactly I want to do a load balance, please suggest how can I do this..

Down means here either the internet connection or power failure happen to the machines..

Answer (score 1):

If you just want to save yourself some typing when some of these machines are down, then maybe a simple shell script (on the client side) like this will do?

```
#!/bin/bash

for m in 10.10.10.3 10.10.10.4 10.10.10.5
do
    ssh -o ConnectTimeout=10 $m
        if [ "$?" == "0" ]
        then
            exit 0
        fi
done

exit 1
```

It just waits 10 seconds and moves on to the next machine, and if none are available returns 1;

Comment: Yes , but I dont want to do from a shell script or program rather than directly changing in linux set up....

Anyhow, thanks for the suggestion.